# from input() reading and converting

Tags: python

i have a dict as utf-8 file and reading from the commandline the word and search it in the dictionary keys. But my file have the characters turkish and arabic

word = 'şüyûh'

mydictionary[word]

my program give me the word 'şüyûh' as KeyError this 'ÅŸÃ¼yÃ»h' back. how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Handle everything as `unicode`.

[Unicode in Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading from a file, you'll need to tell python how to interpret the bytes in the file (files can only contain bytes) into the characters as you understand them.

The most basic way of doing so is to open the file using `codecs.open` instead of the built in `open` function.  When you pull data out of the file in this way, it will be already decoded:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("something.txt", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    # do something with the file.
```

Note that you must tell python what encoding the file is in.

Comment: i have the dictionary inside the .py file. I have no proplem with this but the string who i'm read is the problem. besides i'm under the windows